# Adding list sub-editors to tab panel

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-editors

I use `ListEditor` to allow editing list of chilren and I do everything just like I saw in some examples.The only difference from examples is that I want widgets editing children to be added as a tabs to some `TabLayoutPanel`.

The problem is that I want to give a header to this new tab and this header is not constant but depends on object being edited by newly created sub-editor (so let the header be `child.getName()`) which I don't know inside `EditorSource#create()` method.

```
ListEditor<ChildProxy, ChildPanel> children = ListEditor
        .of(new EditorSource<ChildPanel>() {

            @Override
            public ChildPanel create(int index) {
                ChildPanel tab = new ChildPanel();
                //here's a problem, how I can get tabHeader here?
                tabPanel.add(tab,tabHeader);
            }

        });
```

How can I set value-dependent headers to tabs created by `create()`? Any help/workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was passing `tabPanel` and `index` to newly created `ChildPanel()` and make it `ValueAwareEditor`. Then on `setValue()` I was setting header on `tabPanel` reference at given `index`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this approach work for you :

```
public class ChildrenEditor extends Composite implements
        IsEditor<ListEditor<Child, ChildInTabEditor>> {


    ListEditor<Child, ChildInTabEditor> editor;

    public ChildrenEditor() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        editor = ListEditor.of(new ChildInTabEditorSource());
    }


    private class ChildInTabEditorSource extends EditorSource<ChildInTabEditor> {

            public ChildInTabEditor create(int index) {
                ChildInTabEditor tab = new ChildInTabEditor();
                // here's the trick :
                Child child = editor.getList().get(index);
                tabPanel.add(tab,child.getTabTitle());
                return tab;
            }

      }

    @Override
    public ListEditor<Child, ChildInTabEditor> asEditor() {
        return editor;
    }


}
```

`ChildInTabEditor` must be a Tab that implements `Editor<Child>` then too!

Comment: Please, take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/editor/client/adapters/ListEditor.java?r=9666#66 . It seems that this first invocation of `EditorSource#create()` is done before initialization of `list` field :(. Hence I'm getting `NullPointerException` trying to access this list in `create` :(.

Comment: Ok, my fault then. You could make the ChildInTabEditor a ValueAwareEditor and set its own title then ?

Comment: yeah, I did exactly this. Probably there is no cleaner way. Thanks for commitment!